# How to put music on someone else's device without erasing their data?

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, music

I have a friend who wants me to put my music from my iTunes onto her iPad.

The problem is her iPad has not been backed up onto another computer, so when I plug it in it asks to set up as new iPad or restore from settings or something like that.

How can I do it that her apps and data won't get erased, because she has very important work on there?

It is fine if her music gets deleted but nothing else. Is there a way I can put music onto her iPad without erasing data?

Comment: I don't see any problems concerning this question. It's a legit question to a common problem. It's not ours to question his motivation.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer files to her computer via an external hard drive, from there she can import them into her iTunes, then onto her iPad. She should really back it up though.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of music in the public domain, and some people create their own music, and while nobody is more scrupulous than I am about paying artists for their work, if something is long out of print and can't be had any other way, the best one can do is try to track down the artist and get some money to him.

Don't copy music otherwise, it's wrong.

Second answer is the only correct way to do it.  Add the tracks to the recipient user's iTunes library.  This won't work for purchased items since they're encrypted to a different key.  You can only synch each content type  ̣ ̣(apps, music, photos, etc.) to one computer at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Upon plugging in your device, you may receive a screen that asks whether you want to Setup as New iPhone or Restore from a backup. If the device has already been through the iOS Setup Assistant, Setup as New iPhone only creates the device record on the computer you are plugging it into. This does not remove any content that is already on the device.

After setting it up as a new device on the computer, you will have a selection below Options to Manually Manage Music and Videos. This will allow you to manually select the content you wish to sync to her device. If they are iTunes Store purchases they will be tied to the Apple ID which purchased them.